# Retorno SQL em colunas diferentes, não em linhas

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou testando uma query, onde precisaria que os retornos viessem em colunas distintas, mas da forma abaixo ele retorna em linhas. Tentei usar `LEFT JOIN` mas a sintaxe não funcionou.

```
select u.nome_completo AS NOME1 from usuarios u where u.cracha = 5357 UNION
select u.nome_completo AS NOME2 from usuarios u where u.cracha = 9999
```

Retorno dessa query:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Retorno pretendido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: dá uma pesquisada a respeito de Pivot Tables (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade tinha visto algo sobre pivot tables, mas no meu caso não é contagem, seria retorno da query mesmo. Estou tentando fazer com left join mas tá osso. Muito obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo o Pivot "na mão"

```
select max(nome1) nome1 , max(nome2) nome2
from
(
select u.nome_completo AS NOME1 , '' as nome2 from usuarios u where u.cracha = 5357 
UNION
select '' as nome1 , u.nome_completo AS NOME2 from usuarios u where u.cracha = 9999
) virtual
```

Comment: Boa, era isso ai. Obrigado!